# Yield in anonymous function in PHP

Tags: php, selenium, closures, generator, yield

I was refactoring my code and I was involved in a problem: I want to do something like this:

```
public function myFunc($time) 
{
  $this->otherFunc(function () {
    try {
      yield;
      return true;
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException $re) {
      // Don't care
    }
  }, $time);
}
```

But when I do

```
foreach($this->myFunc(1000) as $action) {
  // Code block here...
}
```

It raises an error.

I think the problem is the *yield* inside the anonymous function. Is there any way to do it?

I have also tried a Closure, but it doesn't work:

```
public function myFunc($time) 
{
  $yield = yield;
  $this->otherFunc(function($test) use ($yield) {
    try {
      $yield;
      return true;
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException $re) {
      // Don't care
    }
  }, $time);
}
```

and ...

```
foreach($this->myFunc(1000) as $action) {
  {
    // Code block here...
  }
}
```

Features:

- PHP: v5.6
- Framework: none
- Desperation level: medium/high XP

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Real example with [Selenium Test](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCase/WaitUntilTest.php):

```
public function doWaitUntil($time)
{
  $this->waitUntil(function($testCase) {
    try {
      yield($testCase);
      return true;
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException $re) {}
    }, $time);
}

public function exampleTest() 
{
  foreach($this->doWaitUntil(2000) as $action) {
    $action->byId('whatever')->click();
  }

  foreach($this->doWaitUntil(1000) as $action) {
    $action->byId('whatever-dependent-element')->click();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Because it isn't obvious

Comment: You're right @MarkBaker:
I want to call [waitUntil function](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCase/WaitUntilTest.php) many times in one test, but I don't want to write the same code repeatedly.

If I can use something like that I would save too many lines of code.

Sorry if I misspelled something. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You're probably getting an error because of mixing `yield` and `return` statements in the same function, which is not allowed.

However, the question of how to yield from a closure is also something I'm looking for..